# Drag and drop problems using overflow auto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello friends i m trying to make drag and drop functionality on my page but i have facing some problem . u can see my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/82jue/2/) . 
i just want that when the user drag the box the top and left positions of the box match the mouse top and left positions please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kamal. It's not an overflow issue, i've checked. Something wrong with your library. It's better way to use jQuery and jQuery UI. Look for [this tutorial](http://www.ericbieller.com/2010/06/24/how-to-create-a-simple-drag-and-drop-with-jquery/).

Hope It will help you. Good luck.